# How to paginate with letters instead of numbers?

Tags: pagination

I'm developing a CPT plugin. The plugin is programmed so that when you visit the CPT, you see a custom template also included in the plugin.

I've taken Jan Fabry's code but can't get it to work. I've achieved the numerical pagination but after a few hundred posts its exhausting searching for a post in alphabetical order ASC.

Any suggestions? Should I use a 's' in the query?

Monkeyman.be's code:
[Custom pagination for custom post types (by names)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18725/custom-pagination-for-custom-post-types-by-names?answertab=votes#tab-top)

```
// Checks to see from frontend if current page is CPT,
// if so, uses the plugin theme template

function contest_templates($template) {
    if ('lucs_contest' === get_post_type()) {
        return dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/contest-template.php';
    } elseif ('lucs_contestant' === get_post_type()) {
        return dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/contestant-template.php';
    } else {
        return $template;
    }
}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'contest_templates' );
```

Comment: *I'm at the point of hiring someone to do this for me* How much are you paying ;-). Just a note, post all relevant code inside the question and explain exactly what your issue is. It is really frustrating to go off site to go through someone else's code and then try to workout with what you are struggling with

Comment: @PieterGoosen Based on your skills and experience, how much are you willing to get paid for this name pagination?

Comment: Hahahaha, no, that was just a joke and should be treated as such. The rest of my comment should be treated asserious though.